# Is there a way to set a default minimum value for an integer with Jinja2 / Ansible?

Tags: python, ansible, jinja2

I was wondering if you can add minimum value to this easily (if the value is 0.0 ... 0.9 it should be defaulting to 1:

```
-Xmx{{(some_variable*0.666)|int }}m
```

Comment: `1 if 0 < some_variable*0.666 < 0.9 else some_variable*0.666`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [max](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_filters.html#list-filters) filter:

```
-Xmx{{ [(some_variable*0.666)|int, 1] | max }}m
```